# Set all paragraphs to be double spaced in LyX

Tags: lyx, line-spacing

Currently I have to manually go to the Edit->Paragraph Settings menu and set double spacing for each individual paragraph in the document.  I'm using the article ( hebrew ) doc class as a base for trying to write proofs in Hebrew.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To set line spacing globally, go to Document ⇒ Settings ⇒ Text layout, and set line spacing to double here.

[image]
[image]